# LOOKUP Function won't output correct value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I'm trying to create an Activity tracker for a game.  However, I'm trying to use the LOOKUP function to track activity throughout 3 different sheets.  However, the LOOKUP function does not seem to be outputting the correct value. LINK: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tdq6oeEFjgxJg6FXvSH2ZmkgRlHaFiD5aycjvezfNvc/edit?usp=sharing

If you look at Activity sheet, E2:E52, you should understand that it's outputting the wrong value(At least based on what I'm reading on the google docs).

I've tried converting this over to one sheet to see if that was the problem, however, it didn't work there either, I tried being more inclusive of the exact letter and number combination and that didn't help either.

I expect it to output the Attacks column for the username based on the Activity1 sheet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS: I tagged excel as it does the same exact thing on excel, however it gives slightly different values.  I'm very confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `VLOOKUP` instead:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D2:D, 
 {Activity1!C:D; Activity2!C:D; Activity3!C:D}, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]